# loading ammo.js with react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ammo.js

I have a custom ammo.js build in my reactjs app I want to load , in typescript.
unfortunately it does not work.

I had to inhibit eslint, prettier to not apply it with ammojs api.

reactjs v16

```
import * as Ammo from './ammo.js';
Ammo().then (console.log('ammojs loaded'));
```

I have this error :

Failed to compile
/home/sancelot/git/courbes-simulation/src/components/Child.tsx
TypeScript error in /home/sancelot/git/courbes-simulation/src/components/Child.tsx(10,1):
This expression is not callable.
Type 'typeof Ammo' has no call signatures.  TS2349
8 | // @ts-ignore
9 | import * as Ammo from './ammo.js';

> 10 | Ammo().then (console.log('ammojs loaded'));
> | ^
> 11 |
> 12 |
> 13 | type Props = {
> This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Since this an error compilation, adding @ts-ignore solved the problem.